# Angular getting URL paramters doesn't work as it should

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to retrieve URL queries as in `www.website.com?a:b`.
For this I followed [this official angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information), leading me to this simple code inside my component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params)
  })
}
```

This triggers the following error in the console:

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Event though it is not mentioned in the tutorial, I add `ActivatedRoute` to my `app.module.ts`. This generates a different error:

> Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivatedRoute: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

I cannot tell why noone else has had this issue, does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code in your `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: `?a:b` isn't a query parameter. But also note `ActivatedRoute` is already provided (along with all of its dependencies) by the `RouterModule`, which you should have set up as shown in https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely in your app.module or main.module file you need to add an import.
If you look at [this link](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy), which is at the bottom of the page you have linked, you will see

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    // This is what provides the ActivatedRoute service
    // You likely don't need useHash: true, so you can leave it out
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve could look like the following:

```
this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params : Params) => {
    // You now have all params in a single variable 'params'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is why I prefer to use parameters directly in the route.

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
{ path: 'bible/:bookId/:chapterId/:verseIdStart/:verseIdEnd', component: BibleComponent },
```

**bible.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    const bookId: number = Number(this.route.snapshot.params.bookId) || 0;
    const chapterId: number = Number(this.route.snapshot.params.chapterId) || 0;
    const verseIdStart: number = Number(this.route.snapshot.params.verseIdStart) || 0;
    const verseIdEnd: number = Number(this.route.snapshot.params.verseIdEnd) || 0;
  }
```

https://www.xinthose.com/bible/43/3/16/16